# My UIAlertView is not rotating from the beginning to the landscape mode

Tags: rotation, uialertview, landscape

I found so many similar questions on this site, but neither of them helped me entirely with my problem.

My ViewController is in landscape mode and I want my UIAlertView to appear in the same mode. I found some answers here, but it rotates the UIAlertView only after showing it in portrait mode.

This is the code I use:

```
 - (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
 {
 // UIAlertView in landscape mode

 [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
 alertView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(alertView.transform, 3.14159/2);
 [UIView commitAnimations];
 }
```

For rotating the UIViewController to the landscape mode, I used this code:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if (orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    // do some sh!t
}

return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

Comment: `UIAlertView` autorotates even if you don't try to rape it...

Comment: if you really need autorotation only, then yes, quite.